# Why does MiniMaxApproximation fail in this simple case?

Tags: approximation

Why does

```
MiniMaxApproximation[Erfc[t], {t, {0, 2}, 0, 1}]
```

give the following error?

```
MiniMaxApproximation::zeroden: "The denominator of the approximation
-0.08806614069746672 / (1 - 3.857220437604407 t) has a zero at 0.2592540447652163."
```

Comment: This error is briefly discussed [here](http://www.ee.umn.edu/groups/com/mathematica/10.0.1/AddOns/Packages/FunctionApproximations/Approximations.m).

Comment: Try `MiniMaxApproximation[Erfc[t], {t, {0, 2}, 2, 2}]`